# DB2 Temp Table not returning Results

Tags: sql, db2, temp-tables

I'm writing a program to email employees who's certifications are set to expire within the next 3 months. Since some employees have already renewed their certification's I'm creating a temporary table of "Good Ids", employees who have a certification that won't expire for at least three months.

To that end I am using:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE GOOD_IDS(
    INTERNAL_EMPL_ID  VARCHAR(10)
    ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO GOOD_IDS (
SELECT DISTINCT (INTERNAL_EMPL_ID) 
    FROM LICENSE 
    WHERE LICENSE_TYP_CD IN ('STD') AND EXPIRATION_DT >= CURRENT DATE + 3 months);

SELECT * FROM GOOD_IDS
```

I've run the second select by it's self and can confirm that it returns ~3000 rows. However when I run all three I get zero rows. What am I missing?

Comment: Remove the parentheses, i.e. do  `INSERT INTO GOOD_IDS SELECT DISTINCT ...`?

Comment: Nope. Removing the parentheses on the insert didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I rewrote the SQL to use a WITH statement instead.

So it looks like this now

```
WITH 

GOOD_ID_LIST AS (SELECT DISTINCT (INTERNAL_EMPL_ID) FROM LICENSE WHERE LICENSE_TYP_CD IN ('STD') AND EXPIRATION_DT >= CURRENT DATE + 3 months)

SELECT ...
```